# Bootstrap carousel caption outside container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, caption

Is there a way to place the captions outside the image container to the side? I tried adding `position: relative` on `.carousel-caption` but this works only if I want to put it below the images. I also tried adding `overflow: visible` to `.carousel-inner` and while this does work, whenever the slide changes, the other images appear in the background as well.

Right now I'm just doing `position: absolute` to position it but as you can see the caption gets cut off by the image container.

This is the basic structure I'm using:

```
<div id="featured-news" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/banner-img.jpg" alt="Banner">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit Amet</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                            <img src="images/divider.png" alt="Divider">
                            <p class="posted">Posted by MrDoom on April 15, 2011</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/banner-img.jpg" alt="Banner">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit Amet</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                            <img src="images/divider.png" alt="Divider">
                            <p class="posted">Posted by MrDoom on April 15, 2011</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/banner-img.jpg" alt="Banner">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit Amet</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
                            <img src="images/divider.png" alt="Divider">
                            <p class="posted">Posted by MrDoom on April 15, 2011</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured-news" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <img src="images/arrows-left.png" alt="Left arrows">
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured-news" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <img src="images/arrows-right.png" alt="Right arrows">
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

[image: The problem]

Comment: Have you tried playing around with `z-index`es? Maybe change the caption `z-index` to a large number like 9999.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this method: http://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/GJbpB

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-caption {
position: relative;
left: auto;
right: auto;
}
```

Just add this CSS in your code to overcome from this problem.